# Version of SQLite.Net allowing page_size to be set on Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, sqlite.net, sqlite-net-extensions

Looking or some advice here.

My Xamarin Forms PCL project is using SQLite.Net-PCL, SQLite.Net.Async-PCL, SQLiteNetExtensions and SQLiteNetExtensions.Async -- all of these are NuGets.

It was disappointing to discover that SQLite.Net-PCL does not allow page_size to be changed from the default value of 4096 bytes and there are no current plans to fix that.
( https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/128 )

This is  blowing out the size of my database unacceptably; I need 512 bytes which would make the database about eight times smaller. So I am looking to use another version of SQLite-Net (for Xamarin iOS/Android) that does allow page_size to be set.

1. Which version of SQLite-Net would be the best to use, given that I'm committed to SQLiteNetExtensions?
2. Will it be best to include SQLite sources in my project?
3. Will the SQLiteNetExtensions and SQLiteNetExtensions.Async NuGets still work with that version of SQLite or will I need to include the sources for those? (TwinCoders recommends using NuGets for SQLite.Net.)

Certainly would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

To change the page size, a workaround would be as follows.

1. In iTunes export the database to laptop.
2. On laptop, open the database in the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox.
3. In SQLite Manager on the DB Settings tab, change the page size to the desired value.
4. Add the updated database to your Xamarin project, setting Build Action to 'Content'.
5. Add temporary startup code to copy that database to the library folder or wherever it is needed.

Have not tried this but looks like it should work.